# How can the Parse node sdk be used to send a push notification?

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

I currently have this code in Python using [parse_rest](https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy), and it works:

```
Push.alert({
    'foo': 1,
    'bar': 2
}, where={'special_condition': true})
```

How can I write equivalent code in node.js using [the Javascript library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse)? Something like this? (in coffeescript)

```
query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation)
query.equalTo('special_condition', true);
Parse.Push.send
  data: 'foo': 1, 'bar': 2
  where: query
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

```
query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation)
query.equalTo('special_condition', true)
data = { 'foo': 1, 'bar': 2 }

success = -> console.log "push was successful"
error = (e) -> console.error e

Parse.Push.send({ data: data, where: query }, success: success, error: error)
```